# Iteratively parse a large XML file without using the DOM approach

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I have an xml file

```
<temp>
  <email id="1" Body="abc"/>
  <email id="2" Body="fre"/>
  .
  .
  <email id="998349883487454359203" Body="hi"/>
</temp>
```

I want to read the xml file for each email tag. That is, at a time I want to read email id=1..extract body from it, the read email id=2...and extract body from it...and so on

I tried to do this using DOM model for XML parsing, since my file size is 100 GB..the approach does not work. I then tried using:

```
  from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
  tree=ET.parse('myfile.xml')
  root=ET.parse('myfile.xml').getroot()
  for i in root.findall('email/'):
              print i.get('Body')
```

Now once I get the root..I am not getting why is my code not been able to parse.

The code upon using iterparse is throwing the following error:

```
 "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 437: ordinal not in range(128)"
```

Can somebody help

Comment: I tried but considering my file size I have been suggested to use 'lxml', also I am not getting exactly how to use iterparse. Also, thanks a ton for replying. :)

Comment: Have you tried `xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse()`  ?

Comment: @Dikie Thanks for replying :) Actually I am not getting the concept of iterparse, though I have tried studying it from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/ ..can somebody be kind enough to explain it by an example.

Comment: @JannatArora LXML supports SAX parsing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An example for iterparse:

```
import cStringIO
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse

fakefile = cStringIO.StringIO("""<temp>
  <email id="1" Body="abc"/>
  <email id="2" Body="fre"/>
  <email id="998349883487454359203" Body="hi"/>
</temp>
""")
for _, elem in iterparse(fakefile):
    if elem.tag == 'email':
        print elem.attrib['id'], elem.attrib['Body']
    elem.clear()
```

Just replace fakefile with your real file.
Also read [this](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm#incremental-parsing) for further details.

Comment: You forgot to say where `iterparse` was supposed to come from.

Comment: +1, but for a 100GB file I would use the LXML version of `iterparse`.

Comment: @Dikie Thanks a ton for the help. The code is throwing the error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 437: ordinal not in range(128)
I have tried converting to string also but still it does not work

Comment: You probably have to open the file with `codecs.open` for it to handler unicode character correctly.